# Create a report that is evaluated every day

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Is there any functionality in SQL Server Reporting Services to run a query every day and graph the result or do I need to use a separate table and cronjob to run the query and save the result plus timestamp?

As an ordinary example, I want to monitor some numbers, generated by a query like this `select count(id), count(distinct foobar) from T_MYTABLE` and show the result per day or even per hour.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create that as an agent job, running at your most detailed interval and insert that data somewhere? Then write the report to run in SSRS that does whatever it wants to the accumulated data.

You can schedule reports to be run through the subscription service; however, reports shouldn't be changing data. It's not that it can't do it, it's that it shouldn't be doing it. It's a very bad model to follow. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/u/41723